# need to directly mutate a property in Vue.js even though it's not suggested

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this vue instance:

```
new Vue({

        el: '#content',

        data:{
            form: form
        },

        methods:{
            onSubmit()
            {
                this.form.submit();
            }
        }
    })
```

and I have declared a component:

```
Vue.component('image-file-selector', {
        props:{
            label:{
                required: true
            },
            title:{
                required: true
            },
            model:{
                required: true
            }
        },
        template: `<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="bmd-label-floating">@{{ label }}</label> <br>
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <a :data-input="title" :data-preview="holderId" class="image-lfm btn btn-primary">
                              <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>  choose
                            </a>
                          </span>
                            <input :id="title" :name="title" class="form-control" type="text" v-model="model"
                                v-on:click="update">
                        </div>
                        <img :id="holderId" style="margin-top:15px;max-height:100px;">
                    </div>`,
        computed:{
            holderId(){
                return this.title + '-holder';
            }
        },
        methods:{
            update()
            {
                console.log('updating ...');
                this.model = $('#' + this.title).val(); // error occurrs here
            }
        }

    });
```

and I have instantiated my component like this:

```
<image-file-selector label="banner" title="banner" :model="form.banner"></image-file-selector>
```

The problem is I get this error of "**Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value**". I have binded my form.banner property of my vue instance to model property of my component because I need to update form.banner when model is changed. And I need to change model when update function is called. I cannot bind change event to my input element since it causes another semantic error. I don't know how to use a data instead of a property inside component **without ruining my form.model binding**.

Comment: Why don't you emit an event from the child and update the `form.banner` in the parent component?

Comment: @StevenB I tried to emit event in component like this: this.$emit('updated', value). and to update it like this: <image-file-selector label="label" title="banner" :model="form.banner" v-on:updated="form.banner = $event.target.value"></image-file-selector>. But $event is null and not recognized.

Comment: When you emit like that the `$event` will be the value so it would just be `v-on:updated="form.banner = $event`

Answer (score 0):

1. you can have the props values as a object (then can use that object inside the component)
2. Like the error said can use the local data property to assign prop value and use it in the component

   data: {
     model: // assign the prop value to it
   }